# IE7 Debugging with Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-express

How do I debug IE7 javascript with Visual Studio Express and which version should I use?

**Update and Answer.** You have to enable debugging in IE, create an empty web site in Visual Studio, press "Start" and navigate the browser to whatever you want to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) is a good option for debugging JS in IE.

To debug from within Visual Studio Express, see [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=535468).

Comment: It doesn't mention debugging javascript. I think that's only available in IE8.

Comment: Visual Studio Express can only debug IE session that is started from its debug session. It cannot attach to a running IE instance. If you want to attach to a running instance, you need a full Visual Studio product.

Comment: No offense but IE Dev toolbar is the biggest pieve of debugger-crap I have encountered in my 18 years as a developer. Try debugging larga java script files like Ext JS e.g. Takes 5 or more minutes to load!! And each time you switch to another stack call, another 5 minutes!! Just to name a few...